# Media Player error in a Fragment

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a little Media Player. Therefor i wrote this code to play a .aac file located in the assets folder:

```
public class FragmentDominik extends Fragment {
    Button button;
    View view;
    //MainActivity mA = new MainActivity();
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dominik,container, false);
        button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dominikButton1);
        Log.v("Syx","In Activity");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.v("Syx","Clicked");
                try {
                    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
                    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = view.getContext().getAssets().openFd("dome__heeey.aac");
                   /* if (mA.mP.isPlaying())  {
                        mA.mP.reset();
                    }*/
                    Log.v("Syx","Playing");
                    player.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());
                    Log.v("Syx", "Playing 2");
                    player.prepare();
                    Log.v("Syx", "Playing 3");
                    player.start();
                    Log.v("Syx", "Playing 4");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

but for some reason it gives me an error, when i try to play the music, so the error appears after the Log "Playing 2", so the error has something to do with the player.prepare();. I have no clue on what is causing this error, so any help is appreciated :)
Edit: Stacktrace

```
01-24 16:21:18.044 730-730/com.example.admin.soundboard V/Syx: Clicked
01-24 16:21:18.045 730-730/com.example.admin.soundboard V/Syx: Playing
01-24 16:21:18.052 730-730/com.example.admin.soundboard V/Syx: Playing 2
01-24 16:21:18.060 730-741/com.example.admin.soundboard E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
01-24 16:21:18.061 730-730/com.example.admin.soundboard W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
01-24 16:21:18.061 730-730/com.example.admin.soundboard W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method)
01-24 16:21:18.061 730-730/com.example.admin.soundboard W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1163)
01-24 16:21:18.061 730-730/com.example.admin.soundboard W/System.err:     at com.example.admin.soundboard.FragmentDominik$1.onClick(FragmentDominik.java:44)
01-24 16:21:18.061 730-730/com.example.admin.soundboard W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
01-24 16:21:18.061 730-730/com.example.admin.soundboard W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
01-24 16:21:18.061 730-730/com.example.admin.soundboard W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-24 16:21:18.061 730-730/com.example.admin.soundboard W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-24 16:21:18.061 730-730/com.example.admin.soundboard W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-24 16:21:18.061 730-730/com.example.admin.soundboard W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
01-24 16:21:18.061 730-730/com.example.admin.soundboard W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-24 16:21:18.061 730-730/com.example.admin.soundboard W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-24 16:21:18.061 730-730/com.example.admin.soundboard W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: then please post the stacktrace....

Comment: Check if `AssetFileDescriptor` is correct.

Comment: the filename is correct and i just c&p'ed the file into the assets folder...

Comment: do You have more than one file in Your asset folder?